# How to build the simplest 12V 2A switching power supply?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, schematics, mosfet-driver

**The problem:**
I need to learn to build the simplest switching mode power supply. If I succeed, I hope I'll be able to work my way up and make more advanced SMPSs for other applications.

**I did my research:**
I've been searching everywhere for a tutorial on how to build a simple switching mode power supply, however, the tutorials and solutions I found look super complicated for me. So far I have looked at a few articles and have used the **PI Expert** and the **Power Stage Designer Tool** (from Texas Instruments) to get familiar with designing the circuit. I know how an SMPS works, but I'm afraid I need to learn how to set up the "switching" part (i.e. how to set up the IC that is in charge of controlling the MOSFETs).

**My Stash:**
Includes 5-PC-power-supplies worth of scavenged components, and I was wondering if I can actually build a smaller PCB that only outputs 12V 2A.

**The applications:**
The simplest one is that I need to supply constant 12V to two fans, mounted on the heatsinks of two 50W LEDs, which are powered by a 100W LED driver. Linear regulation isn't a good idea for obvious reasons.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why to you need 24VA to cool 100W LED's? That seems rather inefficient too.  Try CPU coolers. What voltage is your LED driver?

Comment: Is this honestly easier than buying a ready-made off-the-shelf supply from eBay for $4?

Comment: how many of those scavenged parts are good?

Comment: And... what is your source? AC wall outlet? 24 VDC? - I'm fairly certain that it's much easier for you to just take apart some old computer and use its PSU, because there you have 12 V able to supply 2 A.

Comment: I'd like to recommend Abraham Pressman's book, "Switching and Linear Power Supply, Power Converter Design." It is one of the earlier books on the subject and because of this the book approaches the reader as more of an *interested beginner*. Modern books, I think, now tend to assume a more rigorous background as part of a curriculum. This makes them less accessible by a hobbyist (to my view, anyway.) This particular book was my own introduction and I found I was able to follow most of it when I first read it about 30 years ago and knew a lot less. See if you can find a cheap copy somewhere.

Comment: @jonk Pressman's latest book is "Switching Power Supply Design". There's also a nice book named as "Switchmode Power Supply Handbook" from Keith Billings. They are all good for both beginners and advanced designers. Highly recommended.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks. I don't have Pressman's newer text. But often, new texts assume more from readers than older ones. For example, I would NOT recommend later editions of XINU from Douglas Comer for people learning to make an O/S the first time. His later books leave out some important details and press forward with too much too quickly, otherwise. I will look at Keith's book! Thanks.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Well they ARE cpu coolers actually. I'm just trying to learn to to make a PSU, so then I can build more of it for other devices e.g. small vacuum cleaner, home made LED desk lights etc.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher I live in Iran, I can't buy from ebay but I get your point. However, I already have A LOT of free time and a lot of parts :))

Comment: @Jasen Roughly all of them.

Comment: @HarrySvensson When LEDs are connected to the driver it outputs about 35VDC. I also have a small vacuum cleaner which want to be able to power from a 220VAC wall outlet, in thefuture.

Comment: Ali can you get https://web.archive.org/ in Iran?  All the  books are there.  Billings  makes good comments and adds to Pressman's work on SMPS Design.  Keith designed for us once at Hammond and was one of the best. But the best way to learn is from a service manual, scope and working unit rather than trial and failure.  Even for a TV. But to drive 100W LED's use a working PC PSU.

Comment: You will figure out where feedback is detected and learn to regulate that ratio to adjust Vout in Laptop chargers or PC PSU's

Comment: give that you have roughly several working computer PSUs, using one of them as your 12V supply seems simplest,  you only need to ground the enable wire,

Answer (score 2):

First things first - a SMPS is not a simple circuit, and they just get more and more sophisticated. So one option you have is to start with a toy implementation with an inductor, a BJT, a capacitor and a microcontroller to drive the BJT. You wont get 2A out of it on your first go, and you'll probably fry a few BJTs, but you'll learn a lot.

But if you're keen on building something useful, then you need to pick an IC. It's hard to find much simpler than TI's Simple Switcher series. The [LMZ14202H](http://www.ti.com/product/lmz14202h) would probably meet your needs.

Both the inductor and the switcher are integrated, so you only have to concentrate on the feedback circuit. Follow their application notes very carefully and you should have something running fairly quickly. The LMZ14202H only comes in an SMD package though, so you'll probably want to get a 0.05" breakout board too for prototyping.

Trying to re-use components from existing power supplies is unlikely to be  a fruitful path - those components are likely to be quite specialised, chosen to suit a specific design, and reverse-engineering a commercial power supply design is harder than building one from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn about switching power supplies, don't make one that works off line voltage. The simplest topology to learn the essentials from would be a buck converter. Once you have a good idea of the calculations and pitfalls with that try making an isolated switching converter of some sort (flyback, forward, push-pull). Then you can think about the difficulties of high voltage.